# Illustrator: How to accurately align shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, alignment, snapping

i didn't really use Illustrator before, but i'm having troubles with some basic things such as aligning shapes together accurately. I'm using this auto-snap feature to align things but it's never really pixel-accurate as shown in the screenshots:

[image: Pixel not accurate]

Whenever i try to resize the shape so that it fits the edges of the circle it snaps back as shown in the screenshot. Don't get me wrong, i just want to have the shape the same size as the outter circle.

Comment: go to Window->Transform, Click on the point you want with Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) and copy the numbers to the point you want to correlate (you copy the number, choose the point and paste)

Comment: Is Align to Pixel Grid checked?

Comment: Yep, after turning it off worked as well. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cut out the central circle from the larger circle the object path will run around the remaining "O" shape. The auto align features will then snap to this path easily.

[image: Illustrator Align Elements]